# Algorithm to connect every node between each level of a graph / tree

Tags: arrays, charts, tree, breadth-first-search

I have a problem where I need to be able to find the unique combinations of data spread across n arrays. Each array can contain around 2 to 15 values. In essence I think what I'm looking for is the unique paths through this data. My mind jumps to this being some kind of tree or graph problem. I could do trees and write a recursive algorithm to do a BFS. I'm no algorithm expert though, any suggestions how I can accomplish this?

```
Ex 1.

arr1 = 0     6     3    10
arr2 = 75    10
arr3 = 99    50 
arr4 = 10

The resulting new list of numbers I'd hope to generate by walking down the tree:

0 75 99 10
0 75 50 10
0 10 99 10
0 10 50 10


               0

        75           10

    99    50      99    50

10         10   10         10


Ex 2.

arr1 = 0     6     3    10
arr2 = 75    10
arr3 = 99    50 
arr4 = 10    30    60   50


The resulting new list of numbers I'd hope to generate by walking down the tree:

0 75 99 10 60
0 75 50 10 60 
0 10 99 10 60
0 10 50 10 60
0 10 50 10 50...

               0

        75           10

     99    50      99    50

10   30   60  50  10   30   60   50
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `arr1`? As to your question: that's a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Just search with that, and you'll find plenty of implementations in whatever programming language you are using.

Comment: Thank you @trincot. I got back to it today and this helped solve my problem. There is no specific purpose of arr1 it's just part of a set of data that I was trying to unfold into a larger list but with all the various combinations. I'm building an application that uses a UI to generate permutations of test cases.